# How to show that (G,•) is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group such that $\forall x,y \in G$, $x\neq y$ there exists $H_1,H_2$ subgroups of $G$,
> such that $x\in H_1$, $y\in H_2$ and $H_1\cap H_2$={e} then show that $(G,\cdot)$ is an abelian group.

If I assume the contrary that $ab\neq ba$ then there exist subgroups $H_1,H_2$ where $ab$ is in $H_1$ and $ba$ is in $H_2$. But now I am confused I am going the right way. Can someone provide me some hint what I have to do?

Comment: Hint: if $x\in G$, and $x\neq x^2$, setting $y=x^2$, what do the existence of $H_1$ and $H_2$ tell you about $x$?

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

We prove at first that every non-identical element of this group is of order 2.
Assume the converse; then there exists $a\in G$ of order $>2$.
Let $x = a$ and $y = a^2\neq e$. By assumption, there exist $H_1$ and $H_2$
such that $x\in H_1$ and $y\in H_2$ and $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$.
On the other hand, since $y=x^2$, then $y\in H_1$ and $y\in H_1\cap H_2$.
Contradiction; statement is proved.

If the order of every element of $G$ is 2, then $G$ is an Abelian group.
Indeed:
$(xy)^2=e\Rightarrow xy=(xy)^{-1}\Rightarrow xy=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx.$

Comment: Why do an unnecessary proof by contradiction? Let $x\neq e$ Then $x^2\neq x$, so there exist $H_1$ and $H_2$ with $x\in H_1$, $x^2\in H_2$, $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$. As $x\in H_1$ implies $x^2\in H_1$, then $x^2\in H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$, so $x^2=e$.